# assembly leal and movl difference

Tags: assembly, x86, att

```
leal(%eax,%ecx,4), %edx
```

as I was reading from my computer systems book,
if there`s premises that $eax contains x value and %ecx contains y,
then the above means, x+4y putting into %edx.

then if it is

```
movl(%eax,%ecx,4), %edx
```

, then isn`t the same one with leal expression above?

As I know, leal creates address that can be referenced,not referencing by itself like movl, but

when I saw `leal(%eax,%ecx,4), %edx` equals putting `x+4y` into `edx` register,
then doesn`t it mean that it 'referenced'`%eax`and`%ecx` and extracted value x and y for using computation??

- doesn`t it "()" means 'referenced'??

Comment: then can I ask you something? what if %eax has integer value that is not address? then if it is leal, the error occurs? although it doesn`t matter for movl?

Comment: `leal` doesn't know if it is an address or not, it just computes a value. `movl`, on the other hand, will try to read a value from the address, and will notice if it is not valid (inaccessible).

Answer (score 14):

`LEA` loads an effective address generated by an address calculation into a register. `MOV` moves something somewhere, when using SIB addressing as source operand, it moves whatever is *at* the address generated by the address calculation into the target operand.

So:

```
leal (%eax,%ecx,4), %edx  ←  moves %eax+%ecx*4 into %edx
movl (%eax,%ecx,4), %edx  ←  moves whatever is at address %eax+%ecx*4 into %edx
```

Comment: but then, whether it is movl or leal, %eax+%ecx*4 itself is address, right? :)

Comment: so the difference is, whether to 'reference' the address '%eax+%ecx*4' or not???

Comment: The difference is whether the address is _dereferenced_, or if it's used as is as a value.