# difference between movl and leal instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

Assuming stack as follows where the address of the string /bin/sh is 0x11:
[image]

after `movl %esi, 0x8(%esi)` I think the value loaded form memory address `%esi` will be moved to `0x8(%esi)` (that's the definition of `movl`). So  string `/bin/sh` will be put at address `0x8(%esi)`. But the result is `11` is put at that address. In my opinion, if we want to put `11` at that address, we should use `leal` instruction because `leal` makes no dereference (just an address not the value).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517083/assembly-leal-and-movl-difference

Answer (score 1):

`movl %esi, 0x8(%esi)` is a register to memory move. The first operand is a register, it does not reference memory.

On the other hand, `leal %esi, 0x8(%esi)` doesn't even exist, since you can't take the address of a register, and also `lea` can't write to memory.

If you want to copy memory you normally need to go through a register, such as:

```
movl (%esi), %eax
movl %eax, 0x8(%esi)
```